# Validate only newly typed text

Tags: vb.net

I'm making simple application. There is a textbox and a ListBox. When user type something in the textbox, that text add to the ListBox split by space after some validation process. I done it. Here is my code.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        'split by space
        Dim arrText() As String = Split(TextBox1.Text, " ")

        ListBox1.Items.Clear()

        'ValidateText is a function
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrText)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(ValidateText(arrText(i)))
        Next i

End Sub
```

But I want to upgrade it because the validation process take more time. When user type something in the textbox need to do the same process but for only newly typed text. (From the cursor position forward to the end of the text) already validated text doesn’t need to validate again. I think someone can help.

Note: user can be also copy & paste words in the textbox

Thank in advance

Comment: How do you know the user did not edit text before the cursor?

Comment: Save the length and a hash of the current text. After edit, check the new length. If same or larger, use this hash to check if the initial bytes were unchanged. If the hash fails or new length is less, then there was another edit.

Comment: @just.another.programmer no one can edit text before the cursor "from the cursor position forward to the end of the text"

Comment: @Jongware can you give me a code example pls?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution thanks to [lapheal](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/lapheal/?ws=usercard-mini) who member in msdn forum

```
Private validatedDic As New Dictionary(Of String, String) 'or Dictionary(Of String, Object)?
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        'split by space
        Dim arrText() As String = Split(TextBox3.Text, " ")

        ListBox1.Items.Clear()

        'ValidateText is a function
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrText)
            Dim text As String = String.Empty
            If Not validatedDic.TryGetValue(arrText(i), text) Then
                text = ValidateText(arrText(i))
                validatedDic(arrText(i)) = text
            End If
            ListBox1.Items.Add(text)
        Next i
    End Sub
```